# MySQL query to find values with ID = X, fallback to ID = 0 if X doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a MySQL select query to get all products that have my company_id.  If no results are found, find all products that have company_id = 0.

I can do this via PHP using IF/ELSE, but from reading up about MySQL IF/ELSE, it looks like this should be possible within one query.

This query obviously doesn't work since it will return everything with my company_id AND company_id = 0:

```
SELECT * FROM products
WHERE company_id = 100 OR company_id = 0
```

I keep trying to write it using sub queries:

```
SELECT * FROM products
WHERE IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM products WHERE company_id = 100)
ELSE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM products WHERE company_id = 0)
```

But as you can see, I'm new to MySQL IF/ELSE and this just doesn't work.

Can anybody help nudge me in the right direction to get this to work?

Many thanks

*(I have to use MySQL v5.1.73)*

Comment: May be you can find your solution here http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-function/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to do a simple subquery to get the correct company_id, and then select the correct products;

```
SELECT * FROM products
WHERE company_id = (
  SELECT MAX(company_id) FROM products WHERE company_id IN (100,0)
);
```

This will find company id 100 if it exists, otherwise 0. It then just selects the products.

Comment: That's excellent, thank you - exactly what I was looking to do

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to make it harder then it is. I would just do this:

```
SELECT * FROM products
WHERE company_id = 100 OR company_id = 0
ORDER BY company_id DESC
```

If there are results with `id = 100`, only show those in php. You are still doing it in one query, so no extra roundtrip to the database. You might be returning a bit more bytes then needed in some cases, but who cares. It's clear, it's simple and only when it's obviously getting a problem, I see no reason to suspect issues.